# Opera gestures in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, opera

I am using Chrome but I miss the old Opera gestures (specifically right click + left click for back and LC + RC for forward). I have tried the following extensions, and although they offer some nice alternatives, it's not quite what I am looking for.

This is what I tried:

- Chrome Mouse Gesture
- Smooth Gestures
- Gestures For Chrome(TM)

Does anyone know of a way (preferably an extension) that has the RC + LC gesture functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: What you describe seems to be available by default in Smooth Gestures. It works for me

Comment: Wow, I have been so keen to find it in the options menu I didn't even think it might be set on by default. Great, exactly what I was looking for, please reply to the question so I can mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Smooth Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-gestures/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld) seems to provide this functionality by default.

[image]

There are some limitations though. One thing I noticed is, once you've gone all the way back in history to the new tab page, you can't move forward again, as the extension can't run on that page. Similarly, the extension also can't run in the Chrome Web Store for example.

I don't know how problematic that is in real-world use though.